# Deleting a row from html table without refreshing the entire page in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my route in **web.php** :

```
Route::get('/delete_row/id', 'MyController@delete_row');
```

In controller **MyController**:

delete row from **months** table in database.

```
public function delete_row($id)
{
    DB::table('months')->where('id_month', $id)->delete();
    return back();
}
```

In view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The table element</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>delete row</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>
       <form method="get" action="/delete_row/1">
          <button type="submit"> delete</button>
       </form> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>
       <form method="get" action="/delete_row/2">
          <button type="submit"> delete</button>
       </form> 
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to refresh **only the row or table**, not the whole page.
please how can do that with javascript or anything else?

Comment: You ever heard of ```AJAX```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via `AJAX`. Here's how.

First of all, your route definition is incorrect since your `id` is gonna be dynamic. And you should use a post request.

Change your route in `web.php` to this instead:

```
Route::post('/delete_row/{id}', 'MyController@delete_row')->name('row.delete');

// This is so your id parameter can be any value at all. I also gave it
// a name so we can access it with the route() method
```

Now change your controller to give a `JSON` response instead, this way:

```
public function delete_row($id)
{
    DB::table('months')->where('id_month', $id)->delete();
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Deleted successfully']);
```

Now in you view/blade file, there is absolutely no need to use html forms, since you are gonna be making use of `AJAX`
Change it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 {{-- Add crsf token so your ajax request will be allowed --}}
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The table element</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>delete row</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>
          <button data-id="1" class="delete" type="submit"> delete</button>
       
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>
       
          <button data-id="2" class="delete" type="submit"> delete</button>
       
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
// here is your ajax script

$('.delete-button').click(function() {
var id = $(this).data('id');
var el = this;
var url = "{{ route('row.delete', ':id') }}";
var token= $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
url = url.replace(':id', id);
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'_method' : 'POST', '_token' :token},
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .done(function(response){
                
                $(el).closest('tr').css('background','red');
                $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(900,function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            })
            .fail(function(){
               // Do nothing
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u it's useful, but edit your ajax and change type from  Post to GET

Comment: There's a few... oddities on this answer. Deleting a record should be `Route::delete()`, not `Route::post()`. Also, you wouldn't want the ID in as a URL Param `/{id}`; simply submit the ID in your `data: { '_method': 'POST', '_token': token, id: id }`, the pull it via `public function deleteRow(Request $request)`, (note the name; method names are `camelCase`), then pull from `$request->input('id')`.

Comment: @Jon No; do not use `GET` for deleting records. _Anyone_ can navigate to a `GET` URL, even from outside your application, so _anyone_ can delete your records if you use `GET`, and can guess your IDs (super easy to hammer the delete URL with sequential IDs to delete everything)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for the suggestion. But I've always used a post route for delete functionality. And it always works :)

Comment: @Jon NEVER EVER use a ```GET``` request for anything that alters your database. To avoid security breaches.

Comment: Well, that's because there is no `DELETE` request; `Route::delete()` is a Laravel thing, and actually uses `POST`. You can see it here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#available-router-methods (trying to find official documentation on it's usage)

Comment: @TimLewis I'm well aware of that already Why use ```DELETE``` when it still translates as ```POST```. Don't you think that translation can even hamper my request time by some milliseconds? :)

Comment: To follow Laravel's conventions? If the framework is providing a `Route::{method}` that describes what the Route is expecting or doing, you should use it. I can then look at your code and see "Oh, this route is responsible for performing a delete from your database." Also, `php artisan route:list` will show that Route as a `DELETE` route, not a `POST`. These verbs have specific meaning for documentation and functionality; `GET` is self-explanatory, `POST`/ `PUT`/`PATCH` are somewhat interchangeable for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, etc., `DELETE` is also obvious, etc. You should follow standards 

Comment: Well said! @TimLewis

Comment: Innovin  Tim Lewis  yes thank u I will follow your advices

Comment: Haha thanks  Once again, you're correct that a `Route::post()` _does_ work just fine here (not `GET` though, as we've both stressed). If this is a personal project that just you use/develop, then yeah; who cares to that extent? Information is power, but do what you will with it. Cheers! 